# What's the "average" requests per second for a production web application?

Tags: optimization

I have no frame of reference in terms of what's considered "fast"; I'd always wondered this but have never found a straight answer...

Comment: There is no straight answer. Fast is a relative term, and the answer depends hugely on your context and application.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable, well-formmated question that a person would have & ask on SO, and also what SO people would love to mark down and delete.

Comment: Agreed, although the OP could have provided a little history of investigation.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

OpenStreetMap seems to have [10-20 per second](http://munin.openstreetmap.org/openstreetmap/puff.openstreetmap-lighttpd_accesses.html)

Wikipedia seems to be [30000 to 70000 per second](http://toolserver.org/~leon/stats/reqstats/reqstats-weekly.png) spread over [300 servers](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikimedia_servers) (100 to 200 requests per second per machine, most of which is caches)

Geograph is getting [7000 images per week](http://www.geograph.org.uk/statistics.php) (1 upload per 95 seconds)

Comment: Wow, that is pretty slow for wikipedia

Comment: @JosephPersie Don't forget to look at the post date, hehe.

Comment: It's still showing less than 200,000/sec - the new monitoring page is https://grafana.wikimedia.org/

Comment: interesting, I was just load testing streaming on webpieces on records per second vs. requests per second.  I think requests/second is in that same ballpark(100 to 200) but with streaming it shoots up to 1140 records / second (doing ndjson).  Anyways thought I would share more numbers.  (not sure if this will change as that was tested streamed through 2 microservices into in-memory database...still need to test with live DB.  DB may be our bottleneck and bring us back down unless we switch to nosql).

Answer (score 62):

Not sure anyone is still interested, but this information [was posted about Twitter](http://lzhuacuo.blog.com/2011/12/28/scaling-twitter-making-twitter-10000-percent-faster/) (and [here too](http://highscalability.com/blog/2009/6/27/scaling-twitter-making-twitter-10000-percent-faster.html)):

> ## The Stats
>
> - Over 350,000 users. The actual numbers are as always, very super super top secret.
> - 600 requests per second.
> - Average 200-300 connections per second. Spiking to 800 connections per second.
> - MySQL handled 2,400 requests per second.
> - 180 Rails instances. Uses Mongrel as the "web" server.
> - 1 MySQL Server (one big 8 core box) and 1 slave. Slave is read only for statistics and reporting.
> - 30+ processes for handling odd jobs.
> - 8 Sun X4100s.
> - Process a request in 200 milliseconds in Rails.
> - Average time spent in the database is 50-100 milliseconds.
> - Over 16 GB of memcached.

Comment: One step closer to the sources in case the blog post goes down: http://highscalability.com/blog/2009/6/27/scaling-twitter-making-twitter-10000-percent-faster.html

Comment: @ChinotoVokro Added your link to the answer, too. Thanks!

Comment: @user :-D Yes, it's pretty much historical now. It was a useful answer for me at the time, though! :-)

Answer (score 14):

When I go to the control panel of my webhost, open up phpMyAdmin, and click on "Show MySQL runtime information", I get:

> This MySQL server has been running for 53 days, 15 hours, 28 minutes and 53 seconds. It started up on Oct 24, 2008 at 04:03 AM.
>
> Query statistics: Since its startup, 3,444,378,344 queries have been sent to the server.
>
> Total 3,444 M
>   per hour 2.68 M
>   per minute 44.59 k
>   per second 743.13

That's an average of 743 mySQL queries every single second for the past 53 days!

I don't know about you, but to me that's fast! Very fast!!

Comment: Not sure. At that time I was at IXWebhosting and they were using a Windows 32-bit Operating System for their shared servers. I suspect their mySQL database server was a separate dedicated machine, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I'd bet that number is an aggregate of all hits to that particular MySQL server, and not merely your instance - though I may be wrong

Comment: @Warren: Yes, I was assuming it was the entire server. But knowing what's involved in one SQL query processing-wise, handling that many EVERY second is very impressive ... and that's just the average, not the peak load.

Answer (score 12):

personally, I like both analysis done every time....requests/second and average time/request and love seeing the max request time as well on top of that.  it is easy to flip if you have 61 requests/second, you can then just flip it to 1000ms / 61 requests.

To answer your question, we have been doing a huge load test ourselves and find it ranges on various amazon hardware we use(best value was the 32 bit medium cpu when it came down to $$ / event / second) and our requests / seconds ranged from 29 requests / second / node up to 150 requests/second/node.

Giving better hardware of course gives better results but not the best ROI.  Anyways, this post was great as I was looking for some parallels to see if my numbers where in the ballpark and shared mine as well in case someone else is looking.  Mine is purely loaded as high as I can go.

NOTE: thanks to requests/second analysis(not ms/request) we found a major linux issue that we are trying to resolve where linux(we tested a server in C and java) freezes all the calls into socket libraries when under too much load which seems very odd.  The full post can be found here actually....
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11202389

We are still trying to resolve that as it gives us a huge performance boost in that our test goes from 2 minutes 42 seconds to 1 minute 35 seconds when this is fixed so we see a 33% performancce improvement....not to mention, the worse the DoS attack is the longer these pauses are so that all cpus drop to zero and stop processing...in my opinion server processing should continue in the face of a DoS but for some reason, it freezes up every once in a while during the Dos sometimes up to 30 seconds!!!

ADDITION: We found out it was actually a jdk race condition bug....hard to isolate on big clusters but when we ran 1 server 1 data node but 10 of those, we could reproduce it every time then and just looked at the server/datanode it occurred on.  Switching the jdk to an earlier release fixed the issue.  We were on jdk1.6.0_26 I believe.

Answer (score 4):

That is a very open apples-to-oranges type of question.

You are asking 
1. the average request load for a production application
2. what is considered fast

These don't neccessarily relate.

Your average # of requests per second is determined by

a.  the number of simultaneous users

b.  the average number of page requests they make per second

c.  the number of additional requests (i.e. ajax calls, etc)

As to what is considered fast.. do you mean how few requests a site can take?  Or if a piece of hardware is considered fast if it can process xyz # of requests per second?

Answer (score 2):

Note that hit-rate graphs will be sinusoidal patterns with 'peak hours' maybe 2x or 3x the rate that you get while users are sleeping.  (Can be useful when you're scheduling the daily batch-processing stuff to happen on servers)

You can see the effect even on 'international' (multilingual, localised) sites like wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

less than 2 seconds per user usually - ie users that see slower responses than this think the system is slow.

Now you tell me how many users you have connected.

Answer (score 1):

You can search "slashdot effect analysis" for graphs of [what you would see](http://polyscience.org/articles/slashdot-effect-1/) if some aspect of the site suddenly became popular in the news, e.g. [this graph on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SlashdotEffectGraph.svg).

Web-applications that survive tend to be the ones which can generate static pages instead of putting every request through a processing language.

There was an excellent video (I think it might have been on ted.com?  I think it might have been by flickr web team?  Does someone know the link?) with ideas on how to scale websites beyond the single server, e.g. how to allocate connections amongst the mix of read-only and read-write servers to get best effect for various types of users.

Answer (score 1):

I have a customer that uses our software on a commercial web app servers. The software runs on 40 servers. The software is a 10 year old Java API.

4000 TPS.