# How many requests per second can Tomcat handle on an average server?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, tomcat, web-traffic

I'm trying to figure out how many requests an average server could handle. I'm not looking for an exact answer, just an approximate figure.

The server will tunnel/balance the incoming requests to N internal servers that will do the actual processing. The GET requests will have a max 2K total HTTP size (including headers) and the  balancing algorithm will use a simple and quick algorithm that involves a combination of the incoming request parameters and a small in-memory map to determine the destination server.

The only purpose of this server is to be able to receive as many requests as possible and to decide which server from the distributed environment will be processing the request.

What can I expect from Tomcat in terms of how many requests can be processed per second?
1000/s, 5000/s, 10000/s, 50000/s etc.

What are the software/hardware components of the system that have the greatest influence on this metric?  (e.g. maxThreads="500", using AJP, cpu, network controller, ...)

Sebi

EDIT: average server = Dell PowerEdge R310 or anything similar (Xeon X3480, 3.06 GHz, Intel Gigabit ET Dual Port NIC)

Comment: How long is a rope?

Comment: Only way to know is to test. Set up a proof-of-concept/prototype and load-test it.

Comment: This may belong better on server fault

Comment: @aioobe

There's something I'm missing here. In my mind at most it's "How long can a mouse grow?"

You can test with different environments, breed them selectively, etc. 

The average mouse can maybe grow 2-5x but it is not practical to expect it to grow 10x,100x,1000x. I can tell you a mouse of 1km length is not probable.

It would be helpful for a novice like me to understand what I'm missing. It seems your point  of view is shared by the experts, but I assume the point of this site is to help those who don't get it (yet).

Comment: depends on the genetic code of the mouse, and how much gamma radiation it has been subjected to ... there is no *correct* answer to this question, and this site is about asking questions that can be answered, hopefully **correctly**. There are plenty of books and papers on stress testing and load testing of software systems. This question is not a good question for the format of stackoverflow.

Comment: @jarrod-roberson If the question bellow is not off-topic, how is mine considered off-topic? 

"I have no frame of reference in terms of what's considered "fast"; I'd always wondered this but have never found a straight answer..."

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373098/whats-the-average-requests-per-second-for-a-production-web-application/373188#373188

Comment: @Sebi - it is off-topic and not-constructive as well, it was also asked 3 years ago when the standards for questions were much lower. In your case, only you have your hardware and your software on your network, only you know what you think is "fast", only you can do the leg work to determine what you want to know. Thus there is no answer to this question.

Comment: @jarrod-roberson ok, I guess this is a fair point.

Answer (score 2):

Why not to benchmark yourself? Most simple benchmark coming to mind is apache benchmark tool (ab), e.g.:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 100 host/index.html
```

where `n` is number of requests to perform and `c` is number of concurrent requests.