# Reasonable web server performance

Tags: performance, webserver, performance-testing

I'm currently running some performance tests to see how many requests per second a newly developed web back-end can handle. 
However, I have absolutely no idea how many requests per second I should expect the web server to handle (10? 100? 1000?).

I'm currently testing on a modest 1GB - 1 core virtual machine. What should be a reasonable minimum number of request/second such a server should be able to handle?

Comment: That is extremely application-dependent - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373098/whats-the-average-requests-per-second-for-a-production-web-application

Comment: Thanks for the link! I understand that is extremely application-dependent, but that doesn't prevent one from giving some educated guess based on an average-ish applications. However, the question you linked to provide a lot of numbers, so I'll look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the right question you should be asking yourself is what performance goals I want my application to have when X requests are being handled?

Remember that a good performance test is always oriented in achieving realistic and well defined performance goals.

These goals are usually set by the performance team and the customers/stake holders.

Comment: I asked this question because I didn't know what a good performance is. I can pick any random performance goal, but that isn't really useful. I was trying to find some reference numbers, as fvy provided in his comment, such that I could formulate some reasonable performance goal. I simply didn't know if the performance I saw with my application was good or not. Also, I work for a small startup so we only have a few developers. Our customers have nothing to do with our performance ("it should just work") and my boss has 0 knowledge about it. So it's really up to me...

Answer (score -1):

There are many variables to this question;

- What web server software are you using (Apache, nginx, IIS, lighttpd, etc)? This affects the lookup latency and how many simultaneous requests can be handled.
- What language is your system logic written in (PHP, Ruby, C, etc)? Affects memory usage and base speed of execution.
- Does your system rely on any external services (databases, remote services, message queues, etc)? I/O latency.
- How is your server connected to the outside world (dedicated line, dial-up modem (!), etc.)? Network latency.

One way to approach this is to first discover how many requests your webserver can serve up in optimal conditions, eg. serving a single static HTML page of 1 byte with minimal HTTP headers. This will test the web server's fundamental receive-retrieve-serve cycle and give you a good idea of it's maximum throughput (handled requests per second).

Once you have this figure, serve up your web application and benchmark again. The difference in requests per second gives you a general idea of how optimal (or sub-optimal) your app is.

Even the most modest of hardware can deliver thousands of responses given the right conditions.

Comment: I know exactly what my application can do or not, however I want to put in in perspective with other applications. That's also the reason why I deliberately did not include the programming language or web server software. A web application is not just the custom written code, the webserver software is a fundamental part of it. If I know how much "the avarage" web server can handle then I can adjust the answer myself to how much my application should handle.