# How much tps should i achieve on a single node api?

Tags: performance, performance-testing, query-performance

I just did coding a service with all working functionality, now I am starting to worry about performance. without any change to current code, I get around 500-600 tps. And then I started to enhance my code and get around 1100-1200 tps(just code without increasing vm specs). Is this enough? my answer is "I am not sure". can anybody give me a clue how much tps is ideally for a service node?

PS : it runs on 2 core and 2 GB ram VM. service that I worked on is CRUD with medium logic calculation in it, using golang

Comment: Edit your question if you want to add more information instead of adding a comment.

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: golang, @rustyx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related with your rps(request per second) check out several simulation in link below

[What's the "average" requests per second for a production web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373098/whats-the-average-requests-per-second-for-a-production-web-application)

Personally I think over 1000 tps for a service is already good.

Comment: thanks for the link dude,
I think rps is just shown us how many request our service capability, but it doesn't ensure it return the correct response