# telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FloodWaitError: A wait of 41548 seconds is required (caused by InviteToChannelRequest)

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I need to invite one of my groups members into channel. But I have a little issue on my python script. Please, can you help me?

this is exception

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FloodWaitError: A wait of 41548 seconds
> is required (caused by InviteToChannelRequest)

```
#this is my part of python script (channel is my target channel, users is list of users)    
client(InviteToChannelRequest(channel, users))
```

Comment: My group has almost 3000 members. Should I split my members and run separately?

Comment: What you are trying to do is considered spamming. FloodWait rates are not known so you'll have to put a few seconds to minutes delay between N successful invitations to find out how Telegram deals with spam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Telegram is preventing your account from inviting members to a group in a bot-like manner. You can either wait and retry after **41548 seconds** as specified or You can send your application to sleep after several successful invitations using the **time.sleep(seconds)** by setting a variable to observe this, these two lines should help you with that;

```
import time
time.sleep(900)
```

Comment: Where can we see the exact number of seconds required to wait? No info in official documentation

Comment: @AlexeyKhachatryan Yes indeed, telegram won't give out this exact information as it is a piece of key information for their security infrastructure. usually, you have to guess here. consider checking the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373098/whats-the-average-requests-per-second-for-a-production-web-application and the accepted answers to improve your guess accuracy. Furthermore, you can make your wait timer a variable (not a static 900 value) and choose to increase it after you get an error due to FloodWaitError for the next trial, this should help your brute force. 

*wink*